# Posts deleted as spam are listed in "10k Tools - Recently Deleted" section, until the user is deleted?

Tags: bug, spam, deleted-users, 10k-tools

In the [10k Tools - Recently Deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=today) section, posts spam-nuked (red-flagged) by users are displayed there alongside other deleted posts.

> [image]

I found one such instance of such [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741482), and proceeded to delete the user account.

Upon refreshing the 10k Tools page, I noticed that the post is no longer listed in the [10k Tools - Recently Deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=today) section.

Other spam-deleted posts deleted by the community continue to be displayed in this list, except the spam post by the account I just deleted.

Is this intentional?

<sup>(sorry I can't take a screenshot of something that is not displayed)</sup>

---

Also related to this, moderators can search for deleted posts using `deleted:1`. However, posts deleted as spam does not appear in search results. This post did not appear in search results when I searched for `is:a deleted:1` sorted by newest.

This makes it really difficult to track down recently deleted spam posts.

Comment: I usually use [`is:a deleted:1 locked:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aa%20deleted%3a1%20locked%3a1&mixed=0) which returns the recent nukes.